# ASP.NET Core Identity user creating problem

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to add a user in my database but when I create it it is not added and it doesn't give me an error message. When I add a breakpoint to the Create method the code is running, but it's not adding my user to the database.

This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    return View(new AppUserCreateDto() 
                    { 
                        Organizations = (await _organizationService.GetAllAsync()).Data 
                    });
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AppUserCreateDto appUserCreateDto)
{
    var validationResult = _createValidator.Validate(appUserCreateDto);

    if (validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(appUserCreateDto);
        await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, appUserCreateDto.Password);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.ErrorMessage);
    }

    appUserCreateDto.Organizations = (await _organizationService.GetAllAsync()).Data;

    return View(appUserCreateDto);
}
```

Comment: `_userManager.CreateAsync()` will return an `IdentityResult` which contains Errors if any are found. Can you maybe check what that result is?

Comment: Are you looking at the same database your code is using?

Comment: yeah same database but no user added

Comment: IdentityResult returned false when i debugged

Comment: Then look at the result's `Errors` property.